# Problems with binding objects

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding

I have problems binding the objects that i received from a certain website, i have created the necessary models needed and have verified that the information is correct so i know that I am getting my information, the problem is that I am trying to make a grid with certain information and I´m not able to process it using the binding function, doesnt seem to show anything
Context: I am making a mobile App using Xamarin,I am also using REST to receive certain information

```
 Transactions.TransactionList transactionmade = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Transactions.TransactionList>(result);
```

//used to receive information no problem here

```
_listView = new ListView
                        {
                            HasUnevenRows = true,
                            Margin = 10,
                            SeparatorColor = Color.Teal
                        };
                        _listView.ItemsSource = transactionmade.transactions;
                        _listView.ItemTemplate = validDataTemplate;
```

Also no problem if I do a simple foreach, it shows the information that i need

```
    foreach (var item in transactionmade.transactions)
  {
   Debug.WriteLine("id=={0} .. holder=={1} .. value=={2}", 
                item.id, item.counterparty.holder.name, item.details.value.amount);
  }
```

//problems over here in the binding where i need to access 2nd and 3rd level information, not all of the code is here but i think its easy to understand that this is inside the validtemplate fuction that i created

```
idLabelholder.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "account: {id}"); 

dateofCompletionLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "details: {completed };

amountLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "details: {value: {amount }}");

balanceLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "details: {new_balance: {amount }}");
```

this is the model used

```
  public class Holder
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool is_alias { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bank
    {
        public string national_identifier { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Holder> holders { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }
        public object kind { get; set; }
        public object IBAN { get; set; }
        public object swift_bic { get; set; }
        public Bank bank { get; set; }
    }

    public class Holder2
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bank2
    {
        public string national_identifier { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Counterparty
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Holder2 holder { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }
        public object kind { get; set; }
        public object IBAN { get; set; }
        public object swift_bic { get; set; }
        public Bank2 bank { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewBalance
    {
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string posted { get; set; }
        public string completed { get; set; }
        public NewBalance new_balance { get; set; }
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Transaction
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Account account { get; set; }
        public Counterparty counterparty { get; set; }
        public Details details { get; set; }
    }

    public class TransactionList
    {
        public List<Transaction> transactions { get; set; }
    }
```

and over here is a simple example of the information received

```
{   
 "transactions": [
 {
  "id": "065bf1e2-c39c-49b9-98ca-2604db647284",
  "account": {
    "id": "somebodymillionaire",
    "holders": [
      {
        "name": "somebody1",
        "is_alias": false
      }
    ],
    "number": "8585757136",
    "kind": null,
    "IBAN": null,
    "swift_bic": null,
    "bank": {
      "national_identifier": "rbs",
      "name": "The Royal Bank of Scotland"
    }
  },
  "counterparty": {
    "id": "f39f20a3-15ff-475e-b654-d377df58ee5d",
    "holder": {
      "name": "somebodycounter"
    },
    "number": "8964202115",
    "kind": null,
    "IBAN": null,
    "swift_bic": null,
    "bank": {
      "national_identifier": "rbs",
      "name": "The Royal Bank of Scotland"
    }
  },
  "details": {
    "type": "sandbox-payment",
    "description": "im a millionaire",
    "posted": "2016-06-07T20:36:40Z",
    "completed": "2016-06-07T20:36:40Z",
    "new_balance": {
      "currency": "EUR",
      "amount": "9449.47"
    },
    "value": {
      "currency": "EUR",
      "amount": "-550.53"
    }
  }
}]}
```

The information that is shown is

```
App.Models.Transactions+Transaction
```

Now i know that this is the response from the listview that i had created but how can I show the binding labels that I made to show the asked for information on the other tiers in that list
Most of the examples that are out there are of tier 1 json lists so how can i get the information of the other tiers

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in Advanced :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I don't believe that Forms supports binding that combines a variable with fixed text.

```
idLabelholder.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "id"); 

dateofCompletionLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "details.completed");

amountLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "details.value.amount");

balanceLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "details.new_balance.amount");
```

Comment: Thanks Jason for the quick response, but it still doesn´t seem to work, is there another approach to this solution instead of using binding